# Why does this piece of code for a calculator not work?

Tags: c#, user-interface, calculator

I am a beginner and I took on the challenge to code a calculator, with a UI, in C#. It contains 9 numeric buttons, 4 operator buttons and 1 calculate button. When I run it, It does not run correctly.

For example, when doing 12 x 12, I get 14,544 and when doing 10 + 10 I get 1020.

```
private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    num1 = int.Parse(num1.ToString() + "0");
    label2.Text = num1.ToString();

    if (input || input2 || input3 || input4 == true)
    {
        num2 = int.Parse(num2.ToString() + "0");
        label2.Text = num2.ToString();
        input5 = true;
    }
}

public void button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    input = true;
    label1.ResetText();
    label2.ResetText();
}

public void calculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label2.ResetText();
    label1.ResetText();

    if (input5 == true && input == true)
    {
        result = num1 * num2;
        label1.Text = result.ToString();
    } 
    else if (input5 == true && input2 == true)
    {
        result = num1 / num2;
        label1.Text = result.ToString();
    } 
    else if (input5 == true && input3 == true)
    {
        result = num1 + num2;
        label1.Text = result.ToString();
    } 
    else if (input5 == true && input4 == true)
    {
        result = num1 - num2;
        label1.Text = result.ToString();
    }
}
```

I've also included my code here, in case anyone wants to point out something I've done incorrectly or a bug that might make it run improperly.

Comment: please provide only the *relevant* code that reproduces your issue. We're not scanning the entire code for any possible errors and inconsitencies.

Comment: All that repeated code should be put in a method that takes in an argument for the string to parse. Then you can just call the method from each click event.

Comment: Hey, I edited my question, only including relevant code now and removing any repetitions. I also edited my title.

Comment: `num2 = int.Parse(num2.ToString() + "0");` seems very suspicious. Use the debugger, step through each line, and see where the variables or operations go wrong.

Comment: @DStanley I would assume its the "0" button so it gets added to the "end" of the number.

Comment: I don't think we can help to much here. Have you considered debugging you're code and checked that your expectations are meet? And give things better names. We need to guess what those buttonsXXX, inputXXX, numXXX, labelXXX are for. That one part why its hard to help.

Comment: button10 is a numeric button, button11 is an operator and the labels are simply where the numbers are shown. Sorry, I should've named them better. Though, thanks, I'll try to debug it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit of a guess since some of the variable names make the code hard to understand, but in the button click method it looks like you're *always* adding a digit to the first number and then sometimes adding a digit to the second number (presumably after an operator button has been pressed).

See if something like this helps:

```
private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // If an operation button has already been pressed, update the second number
    if (input || input2 || input3 || input4)
    {
        num2 = int.Parse(num2.ToString() + "0");
        label2.Text = num2.ToString();
        input5 = true;
    }
    // Otherwise, update the first number
    else
    {
        num1 = int.Parse(num1.ToString() + "0");
        label2.Text = num1.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, just tried it out, this works! Thank you.